# Why is my tic-tac-toe player based on minimax algorithm not perfect?

Tags: python, algorithm, artificial-intelligence, minimax

I am trying to write a perfect tic-tac-toe player program in Python using the Minimax algorithm but I don't know why my program can't play a perfect tic-tac-toe game. It loses easily. Can someone explain what I am missing in my code?

**Code**

```
import copy

def winner(m):
    #rows 
    for i in range(0,3):
        if m[i][0]==m[i][1] and m[i][0]==m[i][2]:
            if m[i][0]!=0:
                return m[i][0]
    #cols
    for i in range(0,3):
        if m[0][i]==m[1][i] and m[0][i]==m[2][i]:
            if m[0][i]!=0:
                return m[0][i]
    #diagonal right
    if m[0][0]==m[1][1] and m[0][0]==m[2][2]:
        if m[0][0]!=0:
            return m[0][0]
    #diagonal left
    if m[0][2]==m[1][1] and m[0][2]==m[2][0]:
        if m[0][2]!=0:
            return m[0][2]
    #return -1 if the game is still not over
    for i in range(0,3):
        for j in range(0,3):
            if m[i][j]==0:
                return -1
    #tie
    return 0

#finds out possible moves
def possible_moves(m):
    lst=[]
    for i in range(0,3):
        for j in range(0,3):
            if m[i][j]==0:
                lst.append((i,j))
    return lst

def tic_tac_toe(m,r,c,computer,no_of_moves=0):
    if computer: #initial value of computer = False
        m[r][c]=2 #2 is for human player
    else: 
        m[r][c]=1 #1 is for computer
    computer=not computer

    score = winner(m)
    if score==1:
        return 10-no_of_moves
    elif score==2:
        return no_of_moves-10
    elif score==0:
        return 0

    moves = possible_moves(m)
    score_lst = []
    for i in moves:
        m2 = copy.deepcopy(m)
        score_lst.append(tic_tac_toe(m2, i[0], i[1], computer,no_of_moves+1))

    if computer:
        return max(score_lst)
    if not computer:
        return min(score_lst)


#game play
import numpy as np

def game_play():
    m=[[0,0,0],
       [0,0,0],
       [0,0,0]]
    m = np.array(m)
    while True:
        moves = possible_moves(m)
        #computer's move
        score_lst2=[]
        m2=copy.deepcopy(m)
        for i in moves:
            score_lst2.append(tic_tac_toe(m2, i[0], i[1], computer=False))
        max_move_index = score_lst2.index(max(score_lst2))
        move = moves[max_move_index]
        m[move[0]][move[1]]=1
        print(m)
        if winner(m)==1:
            print("computer wins")
            break
        elif winner(m)==0:
            print("tie")
            break
        #human move
        r,c = map(int,input("enter row and col: ").split())
        m[r][c]=2
        print(m)
        if winner(m)==2:
            print("human wins")
            break
        elif winner(m)==0:
            print("tie")
            break
game_play()
```

**Output**

Following is just an example of one game play in which I have defeated my program. The computer makes the first move.

```
[[0 0 1]
 [0 0 0]
 [0 0 0]]
enter row and col: 1 1
[[0 0 1]
 [0 2 0]
 [0 0 0]]
[[0 1 1]
 [0 2 0]
 [0 0 0]]
enter row and col: 0 0
[[2 1 1]
 [0 2 0]
 [0 0 0]]
[[2 1 1]
 [0 2 0]
 [0 0 1]]
enter row and col: 1 2
[[2 1 1]
 [0 2 2]
 [0 0 1]]
[[2 1 1]
 [0 2 2]
 [0 1 1]]
enter row and col: 1 0
[[2 1 1]
 [2 2 2]
 [0 1 1]]
human wins
```

Comment: Why do you return `-1` from `winner` when the game is not over?

Comment: @m01 because I think the "winner" would return 0 if the game is still in play and that would cause the recursive tic-tac-toe function to exit when the game is still not over. As you see I have used the "score=0" as the exit strategy of the recursive tic-tac-toe function.

Comment: How does your code choose the first move? Maybe you should just tell it that the center field is the winning move.

Comment: @m69 hardcoding anything like this is a bad idea. It's so-called "shotgun debugging": hmm, this didn't work, have to try once more :)

Comment: P.S. and it is not the winning move.

Comment: @m01 Yes, sorry about that; there seems to be a bug in my head today.

Answer (score 1):

You should re-think your weights.

Player 1, for example, trying to minimize the `winner` function, will rather go for draw (weight `0`) than his win (weight `1`).

In tic-tac-toe if one player wins, the other loses, so it makes sense to use `1` for "player 1 wins", `-1` for "player 2 wins" and `0` (neutral) for either draw or unknown.

Comment: Can you explain a little more how that happens? I am returning max(score_lst) whenever it's the computer's turn, so it should go for the highest score in the list.

Comment: So computer is maximizing the score. This means, according to your winner function, that he will try to win (result: 2), or if not possible, to make player 1 win (result: 1), assuming that the other player (human) will always try to draw (result: 0) or, if not possible, to win (result: 1). This is probably not what you wanted.